# Video js is getting paused when switching from full screen to normal mode in ios

Tags: jquery, ios, video.js

I am using video js. 
https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.0.3/video.js

If video is playing in fullscreen mode then it should continue playing after exiting from fullscreen mode.

Now the video is automatically closed by clicking the close button. This button only displaying in ios device only.

Please see the image.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7740747/46749356-8b05df00-cc83-11e8-9376-846286b77c4e.png

```
videojs("my-video").ready(function() {
  var player = this;

  var playbutton = document.getElementById("Play");
  var pausebutton = document.getElementById("Pause");
$('#Pause').hide();
  playbutton.onclick = function(event) {
    player.play();
    $('#Pause').show();
    $('#Play').hide();
  };

  pausebutton.onclick = function(event) {
    player.pause();
    $('#Play').show();
    $('#Pause').hide();
  };

      player.on('fullscreenchange', function(){
      if(!player.isFullscreen()) {

      }
    });



});
```

Comment: Have you tried it with the latest version of Video.js (7.5.4) as there have been recent changes to fullscreen handling to account for changes in some browsers handling of fullscreen.  

If you could share a JSbin or other sample of your player code online, I could take a quick look.

Comment: Confirmed that this is happening to me on version 7.5.5. Have you found a fix for this by any chance?

Comment: cosign.   Same thing happens to me on 7.5.4